# errorLog error in xCode4, wasn't there in beta

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4

I'm trying to compile an app that works fine in xCode4 beta, but is giving me these errors with the non-beta version:

Error:

```
Expected identifier or '(' before 'if'" from this line in MPMoviePlayerController.h:  

@property (nonatomic, readonly) MPMovieErrorLog *errorLog NS_AVAILABLE_IPHONE(4_3);
```

And:

The same error at this line in AVPlayerItem.h:

```
- (AVPlayerItemErrorLog *)errorLog NS_AVAILABLE(10_7, 4_3);
```

Comment: Can you post the surrounding lines of code?

Answer (score 0):

I use the **MediaPlayer** from Apple's samples projects and adjusted the App Delegate header to that:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyMovieViewController.h"

@interface MoviePlayerAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate> {

    UIWindow *window;
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;
    UITabBarController *tabBarController;
    MPMovieErrorLog *errorLog;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;
@property (readwrite, retain) MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;

@property (nonatomic, readonly) MPMovieErrorLog *errorLog NS_AVAILABLE_IPHONE(4_3);

-(void)initAndPlayMovie:(NSURL *)movieURL;
-(void)setMoviePlayerUserSettings;

@end
```

And that compiles w/o any problems.

So I am wondering if you made sure that the base SDK is 4.3 and the deployment target is 4.3 as well because that class was only added in 4.3.

If your problem persists you might want to add the entire header class.